# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'webdriver' selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to work with selenium module for Python but somehow keep running into an error. I have already installed selenium successfully. I am working with Python 2.7.10. I have viewed other posts on Stack Overflow but nothing coordinates with my scenario. Please provide your advice on this matter.

```
pip install selenium
```

Attached is my script and the error.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx")
```

Error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name webdriver
```

Comment: is selenium installed? run `pip list | grep -i selenium` to check

Comment: Yes it is, to be precise, selenium <3.0.1>.

Comment: Maybe you have a file 'selenium.py'?

Comment: i just created my own virtualenv, installed selenium 3.0.1 and ran your script and it found webdriver fine. instead it complained that selenium wasn't configured correctly with an executable, which is correct since i haven't done that. did you use a virtualenv when you installed selenium? more info needed about your specific environment

Comment: Sounds like you called your file `selenium.py`. Don't do that.

Comment: Do you have chromedriver.exe on the folder where your script is on?

Comment: Yes I saved this file as selenium.py. Could that be the issue here?

Comment: Even after deleting selenium.py and starting a new file and naming it aspxscraping.py it shows an error.     from selenium import webdriver
      File "C:/Users/jose/Desktop/Programming\selenium.py", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: cannot import name webdriver

Comment: @Learner follow the linked question dear. There'll be pyc files that you need to delete. The dupe answers all your concerns elegantly.